# Using MySQL "in" clause with a long string

Tags: php, mysql, orm

I'm working with an application that needs to make a where query to the database to return a rows with a "t1.address_city" (a column in the database) that is equal to any of the locations in an array. I understand I should be using implode() to make this into one big string, but this doesn't return any rows - presumably because it is looking for rows that match the big string (which of course isn't just one city, it is a list). Code:

`$_GET["places"]` contains something like this:

`["madrid", "lisbon", "london", "paris", "new york"]`

When the array name, $places, is put into the where clause like `IN ('$places')`, I get no rows. Following the advice of other similar questions on here, I imploded the array so that it looks like `"madrid, lisbon, london, paris, new york"` and then use the imploded variable  like `IN ('$implodedplaces')` but as mentioned earlier, it doesn't find any rows.

I have found that entering each place name in quotes (`IN ('madrid','lisbon','london')`) separately works perfectly, but of course I need the IN clause to use the `$_GET["places"]` since this is manipulated by the user. Is there any way to enter all of the values in `$_GET["places"]` as separate strings with commas in between?

Any help appreciated - feel free to ask questions if my explanation wasn't great.

Comment: Sounds like all you want to do is double up any embedded single quote characters, substitute the double quotes for single quotes, and throw away the square brackets?

Comment: Mysql also accepts  IN ("madrid","lisbon","london") so you just need to remove those square brackets.

Comment: It's not just square brackets... It's an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
$implodedplaces = implode("','", $places);
```

Note that this does not escape any quotes that may be in $places.

If $_GET["places"] is a string you could try:

```
$implodedplaces = str_replace('"', "'", str_replace('[',"'", str_replace(']',"'",$_GET["places"])));
```

This does make the assumption however that you won't find quotes and brackets in your place names.

Comment: In combination with WHERE `t1.address_city IN ('" .$places. "'))")`, this worked perfectly. I haven't used implode/explode very often so it didn't cross my mind - doh!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that you need to do escaping:

```
$in = []; 
foreach ($_GET["places"] as $place) {
    $in[] = mysql*_real_escape_string($place);
}
$in = '"' . implode('", "', $in) . '"';
$query = "select * from t where f IN (" . $in . ")";
```

Additionally you need to check `count($_GET["places"])` because if it's empty you query will have `IN()` which is a syntax error.

Comment: Watch out using double quotes around strings in MYSQL.  If it is in ANSI mode double quotes are used to quote column and table names.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work for me since it is somewhat similar to the solution above, but it gave me a server error. I am using someone else's server so I don't have access to the error logs to find out whether it was something I did that caused it but I will try and find out. I appreciate the help, thanks Frits.

Comment: You need to replace `mysql*_real_escape_string` by whatever function is applicable. Like `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you're using `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out with IN, in most cases it requires a full table scan, and this kills mysql performance  ..

You should check a query with EXPLAIN it see it.

Comment: Not if you use `IN` like `a IN ("b","c","d")` as: `a = "b" OR a = "c" OR a = "d"`

Comment: The more params you pass in the IN clause the higher the change the mysql optimizer will switch from range scan to full table scan. Because your query is less selective